# Ubuntu Boot error: NMI watchdog: enabled on all CPus

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

So, I cannot get Ubuntu to boot on my laptop: I insert my flash drive and change the boot priority and the normal screen of "try Ubuntu before installing" appears. That is what I select.

95% of the time it will not boot. It will simply freeze at a white screen with a blinking line at the top left. However, 5% it does boot, and once it is booted it works fine like there is no issue. I looked around on the internet and I saw people talking about changing `quiet splash` to `nomodeset`, which I did. When I this it will actually display what process it is going through.

When it boots, it just goes right through everything without any issue at all, but the rest of the time it will freeze on a line saying `NMI watchdog: enabled on all CPUs, permanently consumes one hw-pmu counter. #2 #3`

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z7SH.jpg)

**Extra info:** I have a UEFI system but it is disabled. Also, I am dual booting this with windows 7.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Do you perhaps have a new-ish Nvidia card? (I've seen the same issue on GT 700M series cards)

Comment: I do not. I have intel hd graphics 3000.

Comment: I have the same issue, I wonder what the problem is. I have an Nvidia GTX680